# Notepad++ alternatives for programmers

Tags: editor, notepad++

I'm using Eclipse, but sometimes for quick php/js fixes I use notepad++. I'm looking for alternatives. Can anyone recommend something? I use Windows 7.

Comment: Knowing _why_ you don't like/can't use Notepad++ would help us focus our answers better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've heard of/are interested in Textmate then [e](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) provides a reasonable editor on windows. [Ultraedit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) is also popular.

I personally use [gvim](http://www.vim.org/) on windows and highly recommend learning the basics of gvim or emacs since it is really useful knowledge when you have to logon to a linux server and do everything via the terminal.

You also might want to check out the answers to these other questions:

[Good text editor for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733170/good-text-editor-for-windows)

Answer (score 3):

[Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) is a nice alternative to Notepad++, depending on what one is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem at the moment. Komodo edit, dreamweaver, aptana (suite or plugin to eclipse), netbeans, bluefish, etc

I choose eclipse, and integrate with plugin of aptana and sdk of android.

All in one, is my choice

Anyway you have commercial alternatives like zend or phpdesigner